# syntax for shortening this spec to a single line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Is it possible to shorten this spec to a single line?

```
it 'false for incorrect email' do 
  get :check_email, { user: { email: user.email + "abc" } }
  expect(response.body).to be_true
end
```

something like:

```
  expect(get :check_email, { user: { email: user.email + "abc" } } ...??? ).to be_true
```

Comment: thx @engineersmnky - I'd agree with your style - was more just curious how it would be done. feel tree to post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get` method returns the response as shown [Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L391) (as well as setting the instance variable `@response` as shown [Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L541) which is why you can use `response` in the test case ).

That being the case you can leverage this fact and make the one-liner

```
expect(get(:check_email, { user: { email: user.email + "abc" } }).body).to be_true
```

However specs should be readable and easy to comprehend so that most reasonable people can understand what the test is doing.

Thus I would recommend leaving the test as 2 lines as it makes it much easier to understand what is being tested. (The one-liner almost looks like you are testing the return from `get` if you miss the call to body at the end)